# Android. Пуши. Проверка, открыто ли приложение.

Tags: android

Приходят пуши о новом сообщении, если я в приложении (открыто конкретное Activity), то нужно посылать инфу этому Activity, если я не в приложении, то пуш идет на статус бар. Каким образом лучше проверять первое условие?

Answer (score 1):

Объявляем в манифесте пермишен

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

А в вашем сервисе пишите это:

```
boolean myActivityActive = false;
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext() .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 
// получаем список тасков текущих
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> alltasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo task : alltasks) {
   // здесь сравниваем task.topActivity.getClassName с .class'ом ваших Activity, вроде такого
  if(task.topActivity.getClassName.equels(MyActivity.getClass().getSimpleName()){
    // если совпадает, то значит сейчас ваше Activity активно
    myActivityActive = true;
    break;
  }

}

if(myActivityActive)
  // моя Activity сейчас активна, что-то делаем
else
  // иначе в статус бар пуш отправляем
```

Answer (score 1):

По приходу пуша посылаем orderedBroadcast. В Activity динамически подключаешь BroadcastReciever, который отображает инфу и задает setResultCode. 
При вызове sendOrderedBroadcast, можно задать BroadcastReceiver, который вызывается последним. В нем проверяем getResultCode, если не задан создаем нотификацию.